# given apiversion and kind how do i find if resource is namespaced scoped or not using client go

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

given apiversion=v1 and kind=Secret how do i find if this resource(Secret) is Namespaced or not in golang

I know how to get all api-resources and then i can filter desired resource like so

```
    client, _ := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    res, _ := discovery.ServerPreferredResources(client.Discovery())
    for _, resList := range res {
        for _, r := range resList.APIResources {
            fmt.Println(r.Kind, "\t", r.Namespaced)
        }
    }
```

but i only want fetch for particular resource. is it possible?

Comment: Did you already try [`discovery.ServerResourcesForGroupVersion("v1")`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/discovery#DiscoveryClient.ServerResourcesForGroupVersion)? (where that `"v1"` is specific to your question about `Secret`, although you'll still have to filter all the items client-side; `kubectl` does it that way, too)

Comment: thanks @mdaniel, I will try it. atleast method you pointed will reduce the number of loops than i am making in OP. thanks again.